# delete listview items deleting only first item

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview contains many items. Am doing multiple delete on listview items.But when i select only second or third item from listview, it is only deleting the first item in the list and not the selected item.
Please help me to solve this guys.

**Here is my code:**

```
/////multiple delete on clicking listview///////

    listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                              int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            // Capture total checked items
            final int checkedCount = listview.getCheckedItemCount();

            // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
                    // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < (selected.size()); i++) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {

                            all_memories_getter_setter selecteditem = (all_memories_getter_setter) adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));


                            getContentResolver().delete(DataProvider.WRITE_URI, DataProvider.ID + '=' + list.get(i).getId(), null);

                            System.out.println("##############values of ss" + list.get(i).getId());

                            // Remove selected items following the ids
                            adapter.remove(selecteditem);

                        }

                        populateList();

                    }
                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(All_memories.this, list);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

       default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
   @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**And here is my adapter code: 
Here I have added code for multiple delete listview items.**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>list;
Activity activity;

/////**///// multiple delete
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public  ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>list)
{
    super();
    mSelectedItemsIds= new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


/////**/////// for multiple delete
public void remove(all_memories_getter_setter object){
    list.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<all_memories_getter_setter> getall_memories_getter_setter(){
    return list;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position){
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));

}
public void removeSelection(){
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position , boolean value){
    if(value){
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    }else{
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
public int getSelectedCount(){
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}
public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds(){
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}



/////**/////// for multiple delete

public  class Viewholder
{
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    Viewholder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_all_memories_listview, null);
        holder = new Viewholder();

        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_date);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        holder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtFirst.setText("" + list.get(position).getDate());
    holder.txtSecond.setText("" + list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtThird.setText("" + list.get(position).getContent());
    return  convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: you need to remove it from the list. and refresh your listview. by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. and set adapter only once.  Also what does   `populateList()` do?. You should post those details as well

Comment: @Raghunandan well said .

Comment: populatelist()  is my listview items function .when i enter dats, it will populate as list.

Answer (score 4):

[**`getItemId`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int))

> Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.

You should pass **`position`** instead of **`0`** .

**Don't**

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0; // WRONG
}
```

**Do**

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have changed my code as you suggested. But its only deleting the first item

Comment: @teddy you should debug your CODE . Check position at first . Follow #Raghunandan's Comment .

Answer (score 0):

Change your remove method to take particular position instead of object.

```
public void remove(int position){
    list.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in while calling method pass the ID instead of object

```
adapter.remove(i);
```

**EDIT:**
You are using sparse Boolean array which is not updated when an item is clicked.

```
 SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
```

This value always returns zero and selected item is always zero.Hence first item is getting deleted always.

Comment: yes.I have changed. But it deletes only the first item

Comment: Where is your clickListener?Where are you updating mSelectedItemsIds?